# Putting JS obejct to res.JSON( ) is okay?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use fetch as a get method. And I got to know that it doesn't matter if I send JS object or JSON by res.send.
So it doesn't matter even if i put JS object to response.JSON() ??

this is react code

```
useEffect(()=>{
        fetch(`https://qwerasdfzxcvqwerasdfzxcv.run.goorm.io/user/${finalCode}`)
        .then(response=>response.json())      
        .then(data=>console.log(data))
        .catch(error=>console.log(error))
    },[finalCode])
```

below is server code

```
app.get("/user/:code", function (req, res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","https://reactproject-oxzef.run.goorm.io")
    console.log("worked")
    
    Id.find({code:req.params.code}).lean().exec(function(err,docs){
        res.send(JSON.stringify(docs));
        res.send(docs);
        ****** these two line gives me same result.
    })
    
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr: It does matter.

---

Look at [the documentation for `send`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send).

> The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, Boolean, or an Array.

So in one example (`res.send(JSON.stringify(docs));`) you pass it a string and in the other (`res.send(docs);`) you pass it whatever `docs` is which I assume is an object.

So both these data types are *allowed* however:

> it automatically assigns the Content-Length HTTP response header field

and

> When the parameter is a String, the method sets the Content-Type to “text/html”:

and

> When the parameter is an Array or Object, Express responds with the JSON representation:

This means that when you pass it a string (`res.send(JSON.stringify(docs));`) Express will tell the browser that it an **an HTML document** which is **wrong**.

With your particular *client-side* code you are ignoring the content-type and parsing it as JSON regardless, but many systems do not, so you should not do that.

Examples of such systems include [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) (which parses automatically) and the Network tab of your browser's developer tools which is a useful way to debug data and can display JSON in parsed form if it knows it is JSON.

---

If you want to send JSON then pass your object to `send`. You could pass your  object to [the `json` method](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) instead if you wanted to be explicit.

- ✅ `res.send(docs);`
- ✅ `res.json(docs);`
- ❌ `res.send(JSON.stringify(docs));`

Comment: Thank you for answering! But is JSON a string?? I think it isn't so think res.send(JSON.stringify(object)) is ok

Answer (score 1):

`res.json` stringifies the object. This is perfectly fine and in fact encouraged.

From [Express 4.x docs:](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json)

> Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using JSON.stringify().

> The parameter can be any JSON type, including object, array, string, Boolean, number, or null, and you can also **use it to convert other values to JSON**.